# JSON.Parse() not able to retrieve the value of json array properly

Tags: javascript, json

I have to read a file which contains the json data and then parse it retrieve the values. I am using below code to retrieve and parse the json, but it returns the value as undefined.

JSON String

> [{
> "description": "Ensures the contrast between foreground and background colors meets WCAG 2 AA contrast ratio thresholds",
> "help": "Elements must have sufficient color contrast",
> "helpUrl": "https://dequeuniversity.com/rules/axe/3.5/color-contrast?application=axeAPI",
> "id": "color-contrast",
> "impact": "serious"
> }
> ]

Code used to read and parse the file is below

```
 function parseAndGetVal() {
const fs = require("fs");
let folderLocation = "jsonReports/report/nf/";
let testResults = [
    ["File Name", "Description", "Help", "Help URL", "ID", "Impact"]
];

fs.readdir(folderLocation, (err, files) => {
        if (files !== null) {
            const len = files.length;
            for (let i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                const match = files[i].match(/.*.*/);
                if (match !== null) {
                    let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(folderLocation + match[0]);

                    let raw = rawdata.toString("utf-8");

                    let str = JSON.stringify(raw);

                    let result = JSON.parse(str);

                    console.log(result[0].description);
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If that is truly the content of the file, the JSON is malformed: ` "html": "" "impact": "serious",`

Comment: @RandyCasburn Sorry it was copy paste issue, I have updated the json string

Answer (score 0):

This line of the code is wrong. You should parse the JSON directly from the string, not a JSON-stringified version of the string.

```
let str = JSON.stringify(raw);
```

Do this instead:

```
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(folderLocation + match[0]);
let raw = rawdata.toString("utf-8"); // raw bytes => string
let result = JSON.parse(raw); // string => JSON
```

and you will encounter the syntax error others mentioned if your JSON is malformed